# This Not Working Inside Function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I couldn't find a solution to this, but the second this after mousedown will not work. I've seen different things about binding it but I haven't had any luck. (It works everywhere else in the code).

```
$(".rightArrow").click(function () {       
    var stop_slide = parseInt($(this).prev().css("marginLeft"));      
    scroll_size = $(this).prev().children().size() * 177 * -1;      
    if(stop_slide > scroll_size){
        var int00; // declared here to make it visible to clearInterval. 
        $(this).mousedown(function(){
            int00 = setInterval(function() { 
                $(this).prev().css( { marginLeft : "-=1px" } ); 
            }, 1);
        }).mouseup(function() {
            clearInterval(int00);
        });

    }

});
```

Comment: Have you tried passing `this` as the third parameter to `setTimeout`?

Comment: Related: [How to access the correct `this` context inside a callback?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-context-inside-a-callback)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `this` from the `setInterval` is different than the `this` from `mousedown`. Simply use a `self` variable, this way:

```
$(".rightArrow").click(function() {
  var stop_slide = parseInt($(this).prev().css("marginLeft"));
  scroll_size = $(this).prev().children().size() * 177 * -1;
  if (stop_slide > scroll_size) {
    var int00; // declared here to make it visible to clearInterval.
    $(this).mousedown(function() {
      var self = this;
      int00 = setInterval(function() {
        $(self).prev().css({
          marginLeft: "-=1px"
        });
      }, 1);
    }).mouseup(function() {
      clearInterval(int00);
    });
  }
});
```

Each function declared via the `function` statement has its own context (`this`), hence, you need to store the previous context into a variable to access it in another function.

Another way is to use bind:

```
 int00 = setInterval(function () {
    $(this).prev().css(...);
 }.bind(this));
```

This will bind the current context (the current `this`) to the `setInterval` callback.

And if you use [es2015](/questions/tagged/es2015), you can use arrow functions:

```
// the `this` from here
int00 = setInterval(() => {
   // will be the `this` from here
});
```

The arrow functions have no context––they inherit the current context.